# Reformat unsupported files in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I reformat not supported files in Intellij ?

The files I use are `.tpl` for the aria templates framework : http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/latest/writing_templates

Is there a way to configure intellij to reformat code for unsupported file types ? at least the indent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do:
 1. **Settings > Editor > Code Style > Other File Types** here you can define indentation for all non supported filetypes.
 2. **Settings > File Types** here you can add new file type with pattern. You need to click plus sign and add the name and then you can configure a couple of things like syntax highlighting for some keywords, comments recognition etc.:
 [image]
3. Abouve solutions didn't format the code as you would like, but it's something IDEA might you help with. To format it you can create your own plugin which would format non supported (yet) languages. There is jetbrains SDK and [here](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/formatter.html) you can find documentation on how to do this.